# How to access data of another variable by pointing to a slack-byte in a structure?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, padding, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct someStruct {
    int ivar;
    char cvar;
    float fvar;
};

main(argc,argv)
const char** argv;
{
    struct someStruct someObj;
    someObj.ivar = 1;
    someObj.fvar = 2.3;
    someObj.cvar = 'r';
    printf("%u\n",&someObj.fvar);
    printf("%u\n",(&someObj.cvar + 4));
    printf("%f\n",*((&someObj.cvar) + 4));
    printf("%f\n",someObj.fvar);
}
```

This is a program I wrote which tries to access the address of `fvar` by adding 4 to the address of char.
I know the concept of slack-byte. I tried to access that memory, and lo! it printed the address correctly.

```
printf("%u\n",&someObj.fvar);
printf("%u\n",(&someObj.cvar + 4));
```

Both print the same address.

Then I tried to access fvar in the following way:

```
printf("%f\n",*((&someObj.cvar) + 4));
printf("%f\n",someObj.fvar);
```

and

```
0.000000
2.300000
```

were my results.

Then I realised that char* and float* are interpreted differently.

So, I tried all kinds of typecasting from char* to float* to float and also from char to float* to float and that too at all possible points like for e.g., `typecasting the returned address to float`,using `4.0` instead of `4` (which I realised wasn't supposed to work... and it didn't),etc.

It somehow just doesn't print `2.300000` and keeps printing `0.000000`

Where am I missing the concept?

Note that I have a `64-bit MinGW` and adds `slack-byte` (I know some don't) which I've already verified by:

```
printf("%u",sizeof(someObj.ivar));
printf("%u",sizeof(someObj.fvar));
printf("%u",sizeof(someObj.cvar));
printf("%u",sizeof(someObj));
```

which yields `4`, `4`, `1` and `12 ....(sizeof(char) + 3)` respectively.

P.S. I know this is a horrible idea, but this is how I usually learn concepts XD

Comment: `printf("%u\n",&someObj.fvar);` already has undefined behavior. `%u` takes an `unsigned int`, not a pointer.

Comment: `main(argc,argv) const char** argv;` is obsolete pre-standard C syntax. It was officially removed from the language in 1999. What source are you learning C from?

Comment: K&R C (1st edition) was published in 1978, 41 years ago. I hope you realize the language has changed substantially since then.

Comment: It's good to see references for such questions - [cpprefernce sizeof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof). `sizeof` "returns a value of type size_t".

Comment: `sizeof` yields a `size_t`, which is not necessarily the same type as `unsigned int` (and on today's 64-bit platforms usually isn't).

Comment: `unsigned int sizeof()` is not a prototype (in fact, K&R C didn't have prototypes; they were added in C89). Also, `sizeof` is an operator, not a function, so there can't be a declaration for it.

Comment: If by `cpp` you mean the C preprocessor, then yes, you are using it. If you mean you're not using C++, that's what we all assumed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the following is true:

```
 &someObj.cvar + 4 == &someObj.fvar
```

you can cast the pointer value to a proper type:

```
printf("%f\n", *(float*)((&someObj.cvar) + 4));
```

`(&someObj.cvar)` is a pointer to `char`, so `*(&someObj.cvar)` is a `char`. The `%f` `printf` specifier expects a `double` or a `float`, passing a `char` is invalid. Note: `float` when passed in variadic functions as one of the arguments in ellipsis parameter is implicitly converted to `double`, see ex. [cppreference implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion). You have to pass a `double` or a `float` to `%f`, not a `char`.

Notes:

```
main(argc,argv)
const char** argv;
{
```

Don't use implicit `int` declaration and old, deprecated, obsolete style of function declaration. Use the normal style:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
```

- `printf("%u\n",&someObj.fvar);` is undefined behavior. The `%u` expects `unsigned char`, not `float *`. You can print a `void*` pointer using `%p` specifier: `printf("%p\n", (void*)&someObj.fvar);` or cast it to `unsinged int`: `printf("%u\n", (unsigned int)(uintptr_t)(void*)&someObj.fvar);`
- C has an macro `offsetof` declared in `stddef.h` to access the number of "slack-bytes" (I like the name "padding bytes" better). You can: `printf("%f", *(float*)((char*)&someObj + offsetof(struct someStruct, fvar)));`

Comment: Then, are you sure that `&someObj.cvar + 4 == &someObj.fvar` ? Note: printing it with `%u` doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Technically `printf` `%f` expects a `double`. You cannot pass `float` through a varargs function.